# How can i model the age of schema.org/person in rdf?

Tags: rdf, schema.org, turtle-rdf

I have the following task to solve:

> Model the following sentences in RDF (Turtle). If possible use URI from schemas available at schema.org or GoodRelations:
>
> Jonas and Rosemary are children of Peter, who are 3 and 5

So i defined the following already:

```
@prefix schema: <http://schema.org/> .
@prefix ex: <http://example.com/> .

ex:peter a schema:Person .
ex:jonas a schema:Person;
         schema:children ex:peter .
ex:rosemary schema:Person;
         schema:children ex:peter .
```

It appears that age does not exist in schema.org. Is there a way of modelling it with birthDate?

Comment: the point is that it doesn't make sense to add an age triple to the dataset, given that you would have to update the dataset every year on each person day of birth. Also, your exercise instructions state say "if possible use" - so in that case it's not possible, using your own URI for "hasAge" should be fine. Nevertheless, using a property birthDate would be the natural choice in practice I'd say